# How to convert SQL to LINQ with look-ahead (lead like query)

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I have a simple table like so:

```
[Timestamp] DATETIME,
[Value] NVARCHAR(50)
```

All [Timestamp] values are unique, but the [Value] is not unique.

I want to find when each [Value] starts and stops. I have the following T-SQL (SQL 2008), which seems to work fine, although any suggestions for improvement would be appreciated, as in a good pattern to implement the lead operator in pre-2012 T-SQL.

```
SELECT
    h1.[Value] AS 'Event ID',
    MIN(h1.[Timestamp]) AS 'Start Time',
    h2.[Timestamp] AS 'End Time',
    DATEDIFF(second, MIN(h1.[Timestamp]), h2.[Timestamp]) AS 'Duration (sec)'
FROM
    #RawHistory h1
    INNER JOIN
    #RawHistory h2
    ON h2.[Timestamp] =
    ( 
        SELECT TOP 1 
            h3.[Timestamp] 
        FROM 
            #RawHistory h3
        WHERE
            h3.[Value] <> h1.[Value]
            AND
            h3.[Timestamp] > h1.[Timestamp]
        ORDER BY 
            h3.[Timestamp] ASC
    )
GROUP BY
    h1.[Value], h2.[Timestamp]
ORDER BY 
    MIN(h1.[Timestamp])
```

So, given this input:

```
Timestamp               Value
======================= ======
2013-12-18 20:26:00.000 Violet
2013-12-18 20:30:00.000 Red
2013-12-18 20:35:00.000 Red
2013-12-18 20:40:00.000 Orange
2013-12-18 20:50:00.000 Yellow
2013-12-18 21:00:00.000 Green
2013-12-18 21:05:00.000 Green
2013-12-18 21:07:00.000 Green
2013-12-18 21:10:00.000 Blue
2013-12-18 21:20:00.000 Indigo
2013-12-18 21:30:00.000 Violet
2013-12-18 21:30:05.000 Violet
2013-12-18 21:40:00.000 Red
2013-12-18 21:50:00.000 Orange
2013-12-18 22:00:00.000 Yellow
2013-12-18 22:10:00.000 Green
```

I expect this output:

```
Event ID Start Time              End Time                Duration (sec)
======== ======================= ======================= =============
Violet   2013-12-18 20:26:00.000 2013-12-18 20:30:00.000 240
Red      2013-12-18 20:30:00.000 2013-12-18 20:40:00.000 600
Orange   2013-12-18 20:40:00.000 2013-12-18 20:50:00.000 600
Yellow   2013-12-18 20:50:00.000 2013-12-18 21:00:00.000 600
Green    2013-12-18 21:00:00.000 2013-12-18 21:10:00.000 600
Blue     2013-12-18 21:10:00.000 2013-12-18 21:20:00.000 600
Indigo   2013-12-18 21:20:00.000 2013-12-18 21:30:00.000 600
Violet   2013-12-18 21:30:00.000 2013-12-18 21:40:00.000 600
Red      2013-12-18 21:40:00.000 2013-12-18 21:50:00.000 600
Orange   2013-12-18 21:50:00.000 2013-12-18 22:00:00.000 600
Yellow   2013-12-18 22:00:00.000 2013-12-18 22:10:00.000 600
```

Note that nothing is returned for the last instance of Green, as there is no 'End Date' yet.

However, what I am really interested in is being able to do the same type of query against a similar list of Values and Timestamps using LINQ in C#. Not against a SQL datasource, but against a list of POCO objects with a Value and a Timestamp property.

So, if I have a class similar to

```
class VT
{
    string Value { get; set; }
    DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }
}
```

And I have a

```
List<VT> vts
```

of these objects, what would be a linq statement on that List that would perform the same type of transformation?

I previously implemented this using a state machine pattern that kept track of when the value changes - something not obvious is that the time series data may have multiple entries for the same value in consecutive timestamps, as in

```
T1, Red 
T2, Red
T3, Red
T4, Yellow
T5, Yellow
T6, Blue
```

and so on. The SQL works, since it looks for the timestamp of the next value that is not the same as the current value. Is this doable using Linq?

To be sure, in the above example with consecutive values, the end result should be:

```
Red, T1, T4
Yellow, T4, T6
```

So consecutive readings should be merged into a single reading. See how the SQL query looks for the next record that is a different value than the current record in the look ahead.

I edited the original dataset example to include repeating consecutive values. The output does not change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may achieve this using the ZIP-Statement with the same sequence skipped by one element as second input - that is your "look-ahead". However, it does not take into account, that there may be multiple consecutive events with the same value.

```
var firstList = new List<VT> {
   new VT { Value = "Violet", Timestamp = new DateTime(2013, 12, 18, 20, 26, 0) },
   new VT { Value = "Red", Timestamp = new DateTime(2013, 12, 18, 20, 30, 0) },
   new VT { Value = "Orange", Timestamp = new DateTime(2013, 12, 18, 20, 40, 0) },
   new VT { Value = "Yellow", Timestamp = new DateTime(2013, 12, 18, 20, 50, 0) }
};

var secondList = firstList.Skip(1);

var combined = firstList.Zip(secondList, 
                               (first, second) => new {
                                      EventID = first.Value, 
                                      StartTime = first.Timestamp, 
                                      EndTime = second.Timestamp, 
                                      Duration = (second.Timestamp - first.Timestamp).TotalSeconds});
}
```

This results in

```
EventID StartTime           EndTime             Duration
Violet  18.12.2013 20:26:00 18.12.2013 20:30:00 240 
Red     18.12.2013 20:30:00 18.12.2013 20:40:00 600 
Orange  18.12.2013 20:40:00 18.12.2013 20:50:00 600
```

The problem with multiple consecutive events of the same value can easily be solved using Reactive Extensions (RX). Just substitute types for firstList and secondList to `IObservable<VT>`. Then `.Subscribe()` to combined to get a stream completed events whenever a color chages. A call to `DistinctUntilChanged` will ensure that only events with different colours are passed on.

```
var firstList = new List<VT> {
  new VT { Value = "Violet", Timestamp = new DateTime(2013, 12, 18, 20, 26, 0) },
  new VT { Value = "Violet", Timestamp = new DateTime(2013, 12, 18, 20, 27, 0) },
  new VT { Value = "Violet", Timestamp = new DateTime(2013, 12, 18, 20, 29, 0) },
  new VT { Value = "Red", Timestamp = new DateTime(2013, 12, 18, 20, 30, 0) },
  new VT { Value = "Red", Timestamp = new DateTime(2013, 12, 18, 20, 34, 0) },
  new VT { Value = "Orange", Timestamp = new DateTime(2013, 12, 18, 20, 40, 0) },
  new VT { Value = "Yellow", Timestamp = new DateTime(2013, 12, 18, 20, 50, 0) }
}
.ToObservable().DistinctUntilChanged(vt => vt.Value);

var secondList = firstList.Skip(1);

var combined = firstList.Zip(secondList, (first, second) => new  {
                                                 EventID = first.Value, 
                                                 StartTime = first.Timestamp, 
                                                 EndTime = second.Timestamp, 
                                                 Duration = (second.Timestamp - first.Timestamp).TotalSeconds});

combined.Subscribe();
```

This returns the expected result.

The `DistinctUntilChanged` simply removes all events from the stream that are identical according to the Value, so this effectively reduces the input to the input in the LINQ example above.

Comment: Can I add a Where clause to the Skip() clause for the secondList that tells it to skip ahead to the next element of the list where the value is not the same as the value of the element in the firstList? If so, how would that look? See my clarification on the question. I am not necessarily looking for the next record, but the next record with a different value.

Comment: I don't know if that can be done with standard LINQ operators, but the general problem is solved here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/vstudio/cc138361.aspx

Comment: It turned out that using Reactive Extensions, the problem is solved by adding a simple `DistinctUntilChanged`.

Comment: I am going to try the implementation linked to by @okrumnow and see if it works. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you so much. This eliminated 8 source code files and an entire project from my solution, replacing it all with a simple function. I likes me some Reactive Extensions!